# Use Dyamic Pivot query for this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

i have the below table. (no primary key in this table)

```
ID   |    IC      |    Name   |     UGCOS   |  MCOS     
---------------------------------------------------------
1AA  |  A123456B  |  Edmund   |  Australia  |  Denmark    
1AA  |  A123456B  |  Edmund   |  Australia  |  France     
2CS  |  C435664C  |  Grace    |  Norway     |  NULL       
3TG  |  G885595H  |  Rae      |  NULL       |  Japan
```

I need to get the result like this.

```
ID   |    IC      |    Name   |     UGCOS   |  MCOS     |  MCOS1   
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1AA  |  A123456B  |  Edmund   |  Australia  |  Denmark  |  France
2CS  |  C435664C  |  Grace    |  Norway     |  NULL     |  NULL
3TG  |  G885595H  |  Rae      |  NULL       |  Japan    |  NULL
```

Did googled around and seems like PIVOT is what i need to do that. However i am not sure how can that be implemented to my tables. It would be great help if somebody can help me with it. Thanks!

Comment: Do you need dedicated columns in your output (like `MCOS,MCOS1,MCOS2 ...`)? Is there an upper limit? Woudl a concatenated result in one single column (like `MCOS` containing `Denmark, France` also fit to your needs?

Comment: Why not `France | Denmark` ?

Comment: @Shnugo Yes there will be MCOS, MCOS1, MCOS2 etc without upper limit. I cant do with concatenated result. i have to split the columns.

Comment: Devora, I just placed an answer with dynamic SQL. This should be what you need...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll create a second answer, as this approach is something completely different from my first:

This dynamic query will first find the max count of a distinct ID and then build a dynamic pivot

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTbl (ID VARCHAR(100),IC VARCHAR(100),Name VARCHAR(100),UGCOS VARCHAR(100),MCOS VARCHAR(100))  
INSERT INTO #tmpTbl VALUES
 ('1AA','A123456B','Edmund','Australia','Denmark')    
,('1AA','A123456B','Edmund','Australia','France')   
,('1AA','A123456B','Edmund','Australia','OneMore')   
,('2CS','C435664C','Grace','Norway',NULL)     
,('3TG','G885595H','Rae',NULL,'Japan');
GO

DECLARE @maxCount INT=(SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) FROM #tmpTbl GROUP BY ID ORDER BY COUNT(ID) DESC);
DECLARE @colNames VARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    STUFF
    (
        (
        SELECT TOP(@maxCount)
               ',MCOS' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS VARCHAR(10))
        FROM sys.objects --take any large table or - better! - an numbers table or a tally CTE
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,1,''
    )
);

DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)=
'SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT *
          ,''MCOS'' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS colName 
    FROM #tmpTbl
) AS tbl
PIVOT
(
    MIN(MCOS) FOR colName IN(' + @colNames + ')
) AS p';

EXEC(@cmd);
GO

DROP TABLE #tmpTbl;
```

The result

```
1AA A123456B    Edmund  Australia   Denmark France  OneMore
2CS C435664C    Grace   Norway      NULL    NULL    NULL
3TG G885595H    Rae     NULL        Japan   NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Now i need to understand ur code and apply to UGCOS too, and then integrate into my actual query. That initial table was actually a joined table from multiples tables. lol. hope it works.

Comment: @Devora, ad "understand": The lower half ist a pivot query, where the column names (`MCOS1,MCOS2,MMCOS3 ...`) are filled in via string method. These column names where build as comma separated string before using the `STUFF-SELECT FOR XML PATH()` trick. The final `EXEC` will execute the command. ad "the same for UGCOS" Please place a new question for this. Pivoting with more than one column is not trivial (read about `Pivot with aggregates and GROUP BY `)

Answer (score 2):

This is a suggestion with a concatenated result:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTbl (ID VARCHAR(100),IC VARCHAR(100),Name VARCHAR(100),UGCOS VARCHAR(100),MCOS VARCHAR(100))  
INSERT INTO #tmpTbl VALUES
 ('1AA','A123456B','Edmund','Australia','Denmark')    
,('1AA','A123456B','Edmund','Australia','France')   
,('2CS','C435664C','Grace','Norway',NULL)     
,('3TG','G885595H','Rae',NULL,'Japan');

SELECT ID,IC,Name,UGCOS,
       (
        STUFF(
          (
            SELECT ' ,' + x.MCOS
            FROM #tmpTbl AS x
            WHERE x.ID=outerTbl.ID
            FOR XML PATH('')
          ),1,2,''
        )
       ) AS MCOS
FROM #tmpTbl AS outerTbl
GROUP BY ID,IC,Name,UGCOS;
GO
DROP TABLE #tmpTbl;
```

The result

```
1AA A123456B    Edmund  Australia   Denmark ,France
2CS C435664C    Grace   Norway      NULL
3TG G885595H    Rae     NULL        Japan
```

Comment: what is the purpose of this answer exactly for this Scenario ??

Comment: Yes, He had asked in Pivot query not in comma separated string you have given above

Comment: you are in dire need to get reputation . That's may be the reason you are taking yourself So Serious

Comment: yes it's open for suggestions but what have ordered ? what have served it should be like that .SO have asked a thing give something not everything ..gotcha Happy coding to you also

Comment: you are taking to personally I think . It's not for the votes I'm just asking what the purpose it serves for SO when you have already given Dynamic Pivot Answer

Comment: @mohan111 The dynamic pivot answer was much later... Maybe this is the misunderstanding...

Answer (score 1):

Using Cross Apply and Pivot we can achieve this

```
 DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
        ( ID  varchar(3),  IC  varchar(8),  Name  varchar(6),  UGCOS  varchar(9),  MCOS  varchar(7))
    ;

    INSERT INTO @Table1
        ( ID ,  IC ,  Name ,  UGCOS ,  MCOS )
    VALUES
        ('1AA', 'A123456B', 'Edmund', 'Australia', 'Denmark'),
        ('1AA', 'A123456B', 'Edmund', 'Australia', 'France'),
        ('2CS', 'C435664C', 'Grace', 'Norway', NULL),
        ('3TG', 'G885595H', 'Rae', NULL, 'Japan')
    ;
    Select ID ,  IC ,  Name ,  UGCOS,MAX([MCOS1])[MCOS1],MAX([MCOS2])[MCOS2] from (
    select ID ,  IC ,  Name ,  UGCOS ,  MCOS,col,val,col +''+CAST(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY col) AS VARCHAR)RN from @Table1
    CROSS APPLY (values('MCOS',MCOS))CS(col,val))T
    PIVOT (MAX(val) FOR RN IN ([MCOS1],[MCOS2]))PVT
    GROUP BY ID ,  IC ,  Name ,  UGCOS
```

Comment: Add `('1AA', 'A123456B', 'Edmund', 'Australia', 'Russia'),` to `@Table1` and `Russia` will not shown

Comment: SO asked question how to get that result set in PIVOT as per Output I have given. So will modify according to his Data @RuslanK.

Answer (score 0):

Do you always have a maximum of 2 rows of data that you'll want to turn into columns? If so, this would do you;

```
CREATE TABLE #TableName (ID varchar(3), IC varchar(8), Name varchar(6), UCGOS varchar(9), MCOS varchar(7))
INSERT INTO #TableName
VALUES
('1AA','A123456B','Edmund','Australia','Denmark')
,('1AA','A123456B','Edmund','Australia','France')
,('2CS','C435664C','Grace','Norway',NULL)
,('3TG','G885595H','Rae',NULL,'Japan')

SELECT DISTINCT a.ID
    ,a.IC
    ,a.NAME
    ,a.UCGOS
    ,b.Mcos1 MCOS
    ,c.Mcos2 MCOS1
FROM #TableName a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ID
        ,MAX(MCOS) Mcos1
    FROM #TableName
    GROUP BY ID
    ) b ON a.ID = b.ID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ID
        ,MIN(MCOS) Mcos2
    FROM #TableName
    GROUP BY ID
    ) c ON a.ID = c.ID
    AND (
        b.ID = c.ID
        AND b.Mcos1 <> c.Mcos2
        )

DROP TABLE #TableName
```

Gives you the result you're after.

Comment: No rich, it will be dynamic. meaning Edmund might have another MCOS in Japan. and it should appear under the column name 'MCSO2'